# Asp.NET Erro Click do Asp:button

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho uma tela onde possuo alguns botões e ao clicar sobre os botões me devolve o erro na tela:

> "Index was out of Range Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection."

O mais estranho é que no evento click destes botões há um `try/catch`, e dentro do catch um método que loga os erros ocorridos no sistema.

*Resumindo: não está entrando evento "Click" do botão..*

Para dificultar, o erro só ocorre em produção, em desenvolvimento não.. e não tenho como acessar o ambiente de produção.

Fazendo alguns testes aqui descobri que, se eu acessar a pagina do sistema utilizando "https" os botões funcionam normalmente, já com o "http" da esse erro de "index was out...". Esse erro começou a ocorrer desde a última subida em produção.

Answer (score 0):

O erro é característico de tentar acessar alguma posição do Array com um índice negativo.

Se o evento não chega no click, é porque antes de executar o evento **Click**, no fluxo da **Page**, sempre é executado o evento **Page_Load**. Então, pode haver algum código neste evento que esteja causando o erro.

Se postar o seu código, podemos solucionar com maior precisão.

Comment: Fazendo alguns testes aqui descobri que, se eu acessar a pagina do sistema utilizando "https" os botões funcionam normalmente, já com o "http" da esse erro de "index was out...".

Comment: Antes isso nao ocorria, sempre acessamos sem o "https", pq inclusive tinhamos problemas com isso..e desde a ultima subida para produção isso começou a ocorrer..tem ideia do pq disso? o pessoal de redes diz que é algo da aplicação..

Comment: Teria como enviar o código do que é feito no botão e no page_load?